# Some troubles with html and css I can't fix

Tags: html, css

This is how page looks:
[image]

First problem, that

[image]

If you look closer at this, it's a bit transparent, we can see div main behind this ul inside ul.

Second if we zoom the browser up... this happens

[image]

I would like this text no nowrap, just 3 and 4 li element won't fit in this zoomed screen and we won't see this.

And for last

I would like main to fit the rest of the screen we got (at least the rest, until there is no content that goes in width or height more)

To look like this:

[image]

Just main to at Minimum fill rest of the free space on website, and I don't want to do it by whole body background color declaration.

Whole code:

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Nazwa Strony</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">0 Komentarze do moderacji</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dodaj nowy</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Post</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stronę</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Usuń cały cache</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="aside">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Deszbord</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Posty</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Strony</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Wygląd</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Użytkownicy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ustawienia</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="main">
    asdasdasd
    </div>
</body>


#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #23282d;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    z-index: 100;
}
#header a {
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#header ul, #header ul li ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
}
#header ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 70px;
}
#header ul li ul {
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    background-color: #EEE;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#header ul li ul a {
    color: #000;
}
#header ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#header ul li ul li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#aside {
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 170px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 40px;
    background-color: #323435;
    border-top: 2px dotted #333;
}
#aside ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#aside ul li {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#aside ul li a {
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#header a:hover, #aside a:hover{
    color: #2295cc;
}
#main {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    left: 170px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

```css
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #23282d;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    z-index: 100;
}
#header a {
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#header ul, #header ul li ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
}
#header ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 70px;
}
#header ul li ul {
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    background-color: #EEE;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#header ul li ul a {
    color: #000;
}
#header ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#header ul li ul li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#aside {
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 170px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 40px;
    background-color: #323435;
    border-top: 2px dotted #333;
}
#aside ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#aside ul li {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#aside ul li a {
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#header a:hover, #aside a:hover{
    color: #2295cc;
}
#main {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    left: 170px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="header">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Nazwa Strony</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">0 Komentarze do moderacji</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dodaj nowy</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Post</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stronę</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Usuń cały cache</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="aside">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Deszbord</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Posty</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Strony</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Wygląd</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Użytkownicy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ustawienia</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="main">
    asdasdasd
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: the zoom issue comes from position fixed this and fix height 20px! try to make few elements position relative!

Comment: What elements, I'm trying to change and nothing changes. I don't understand your point

Comment: No one know how to do this?

Comment: the problem is ur whole css i thin nobody has time to rewrite this